# Adding LI to sortable UL in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to create a sortable for files. When an item is dragged a 'new folder' should come up. When an item is dragged there there should be a new folder added to the UL.

Maybe it gets clearer on this page I set up on jsFiddle: [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/Patrick/HFqTt/). As soon as a file is dragged to 'new folder' it should be inserted in the list and the list should maintain it's sortable possibilities. Right now all the code does is take the file and hide itself (as programmed).

I'm trying to figure out what the best way would be. Right now I add the item and make it hidden. The trick then would be to somehow copy the item before it's hidden and install that in the list, then empty out the 'new folder' item to be used for the next file.

Another way would be to create the new folder on the 'start'-event, but I had a lot of problems giving that it's sortable properties. Any idea's?

Comment: Actually I found that sub level items will move up to the top so long as the top items are not floated (you can use inline block instead)...

Comment: Still having trouble with making a drop down  out of second level items on top level items that do not already have children